# Log all client requests?

Tags: dynamic-analysis, proxy

I'm working with Burp 1.6. *Intercept* is off, and I want to log all client requests.

Visiting Burp's [help page on logging](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/options_misc.html#logging) page, there's supposed to be an Options tab or Misc tab (I can't quite ll which it should have). Unfortunately, I don't see either of them. The tabs I have are *Targets*, *Proxy*, ..., *Alerts*. There is an *Option* tab, but it does not provide any logging options. Only *Authentication*, *Upstream Proxy*, etc.

Where, exactly, do I ensure logging of all requests (and responses) is enabled?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about reverse engineering, but rather about using an information security tool. Please post to http://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Jason - according to the [Help Center](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), both (1) software analysis and (2) tools commonly used for reverse engineering hardware or software are on-topic a RE.SE.

Comment: Burp Suite is not a software analysis tool, nor is it used for reverse engineering hardware or software. It's used for finding web application security vulnerabilities, and thus the question belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jason - I'm using it to reverse a communication protocol; not find web vulnerabilities.

Comment: Be that as it may, it's still a tool more commonly used in the information security industry, and thus the question belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Reversers are much more likely to use tools like wireshark, and the average security specialist is likely to have more experience with burp than the average network protocol reversal specialist. So, no matter if the question is on- or offtopic, the security.stackexchange.com community will be more experienced and more likely to be able to answer the question, especially as there are no answers after 15 hours,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after reviewing the answers, this indeed seems more appropriate to other SE sites

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed the second tab panel.
After selecting *Options* in the first tab panel, there is an *Misc* item in the second tab panel, which seem to be what you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Fiddler2** instead of **BurpSuite**.
It will log anything (I've had apps that Burp couldn't catch, only Fiddler or Wireshark)
Each situation requires a different tool.
Also, on a lower level, use **Wireshark**.